# ssrs subscription runs only once and then errors

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, shared, schedule, subscriptions

Good Morning all,
 I have a series of Sales Rep reports that runs on shared schedule subscriptions.
I have a monthly shared schedule that runs and a weekly shared schedule that runs.
The weekly schedule report runs the first time and never runs again. When I go into Manage and Subscriptions, the Weekly Report Parameter Values are empty. There is a yellow triangle exclamation message that says "One or more report parameters have an invalid parameter value." The Monthly subscription looks fine and still populated with correct parameter.

To let you know how I set these up, I first created weekly and monthly parameters in the report itself.
I created 11 reports for each Rep. In my queries where clause I created a 
[>=@StartDate and an <=@EndDate] parameter.
Under "Parameters" I see those two parameters I created. Both parameters are DateTime with no null or multiples allowed.
Available values have two values:
Under @StartDate
"Month Start" =DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), "1").AddMonths(-1)
"Week Start"  =DateAdd("d", -8, Today())
Under @EndDate
"End of Month" =DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1)
"End of Week"  =DateAdd("d", -1, Today())

I have tried a regular subscription schedule and a shared subscription schedule. The same thing happens, the weekly runs once and never again.
I have the schedule set to run at 7:30am every Mon of every week.
The shared monthly schedule is a once a month on the 1st of every month.
Under Report Parameter Values I see two drop downs "Start Date" and "End Date" and my report parameters "Month Start" and "Week Start along with "End of Month" and "End of Week" are in there - in that order.

I do not have "Default" parameters set up. The parameters checked say prompt user.
Processing says to Run with the most current data and Do not cache temporary copies of this report. There is no snapshot setup either. 
When I did have "Allow Report history to be created manually" it also gave errors. So I unchecked it.
I am desperately trying to find a reason for the subscription failure. I believe it might be my date formula calculating from the report parameter.... I just don't know. I'm under the gun. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not have "Default" parameters set up

This may be your problem.  A subscription cannot prompt anyone for parameters - there's no human there to supply them.  You need to either provide defaults, or enter values for the subscription.

If I misunderstood, and you do provide parameter values for the subscription, try looking in the SSRS log files - they'll be in ...\Reporting Services\LogFiles\, and may contain a more verbose error to help you determine where the actual problem lies.

Comment: this is what I was thinking might be an issue - I am not sure how to get a monthly or weekly option out of one report. I will make one report for weekly and one for monthly just to be able to use default values. I am going to try this today.

Comment: If the report itself, when run manually, could work for both weekly and monthly parameters, then you can probably simply create two subscriptions - one configured with the week-run parameters, one with the month-run parameters.

Comment: It does run manually for both weekly and monthly. Also, the subscription I set for monthly and weekly, actually runs successfully only once. It almost looks like, what you said before, that because there is no default, the parameters don't stay for the second (weekly) choice. Only monthly (first in list) stays. After 5 today, I am going to duplicate all 33 reports for my weekly sub. they will only have the weekly parameter do I can default that version.

Comment: I should also say I have two subs, each rep report one is for monthly, and one is for weekly. I just created another set of reports and I am going to set them to default like you said. I have a good feeling about this.

Comment: I set up default parameters and it still bombed out. But only for the weekly. I checked the shared schedule, for weekly. The Shared Schedule kept resetting itself to "Day" instead of "Week" under the section "Schedule Details". I just kept it "Day" and as a daily schedule have it now run every "Mon" at 7  am. It did not reset itself.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when I used date parameters in a data driven subscription I had to switch to text instead of date columns because of date conversion issues: You can have a datetime parameter and a datetime column but SSRS converts it to a text in between.

So instead of a query with a datetime column I returned a varchar like this:

```
select convert(varchar(50), getdate(), 120) MyDateParam
```

which will give you the "universal" yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss format. (more formats here if you need them. Pick one with yyyy-mm-dd http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

This way you have control over the conversion to text and make sure it is something SSRS understands when it converts it back to datetime. This was in SSRS 2005 by the way. I don't think you need to change your report parameter to text but you may need to if SSRS complains.

Comment: Thanks @H B. Would the report run a subscription at all if this were an issue? My sub runs once and loses the focus on the parameter...and only the weekly one so far. The weekly is in second position, the monthly is in 1st position and doesn't blank out after it runs.

Comment: Hi, no the subscription would not run at all. Seeing your comments it appears you have a different problem than what I described. You use a regular subscription, not a data-driven subscription, correct? Maybe if you create a new dataset that returns weekly or monthly dates based on a 3rd parameter ("last week" or "last month", then base your start and end date parameters on that dataset you can fool SSRS into thinking all parameters are entered. I could elaborate on that in an answer if you like.

Comment: Believe it or not, I think saw this as an option on this or a similar site when I was setting this whole thing up, but I got confused and gave up. I ended up[ created copies of each report - one with a weekly default and the other with a monthly default. So far so good.